# How much official communication was there between the Senate and the Jedi Council?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

The fan video [What if "Star Wars Episode I" Was Good](https://youtu.be/VgICnbC2-_Y?t=5m34s) suggests that the script might have been improved if Palpatine was not a senator, but rather the full-time liaison between the Jedi Council and the Senate (thus allowing him to personally know each of the Jedi and be able to keep a closer eye on their actions). However, I don't see any evidence that this sort of position actually exists in canon. This made me wonder; who has the official authority to talk with the Jedi Council on behalf of the Senate (or vice versa), and how often?

In *The Phantom Menace*, we see that the Jedi Council and the Senate really don't talk too much. We know from the opening crawl that "the Supreme Chancellor has secretly dispatched two Jedi Knights" to investigate the issues on Naboo, so he is at least in communication with the Jedi Council. For the rest of the movie, the Jedi Council is really only involved with the Senate because they are already involved with Queen Amidala. I'm not sure if there were other communication channels between the Senate and the Jedi Council that were described in non-movie media.

So how much official communication was there between the Senate and the Jedi Council? Who from the Senate had the authority to talk with them and how frequent was that communication?

<sub>Legends information is very much welcome, but any answers with Legends info should also contain Disney canon information.</sub>

Comment: At one point the Senator from Naboo was secretly married to a member of the Jedi Council. Does that count?

Comment: @Valorum I've clarified that I'm looking for official communication. Anakin talking with Padmé about sand isn't the sort of thing I had in mind.

Comment: @Thunderforge - But it's coarse and rough and irritating and it gets everywhere. Clearly he meant this as a metaphor for trade tariffs.

Comment: @Valorum - "lucky" takes a new meaning in context :) Thanks for update!

Comment: @Thunderforge - you don't get any more official than marriage. they got papers and everything. there's a deleted scene where they decide if they are filing joint or separate tax returns.

Comment: My username is unusually relevant. I shall go and ask myself.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida Well, it was a secret arrangement that neither the Jedi Council nor the Senate knew about, and they got married as individuals, not as some sort of political marriage to join the two groups. If there's a better phrase I can use, let me know.

Comment: @Valorum You may think it's relevant, but I'm going to give a Vote of No Confidence.

Comment: You wouldn't be the first, nor, I suspect, the last.

Comment: @Thunderforge - sorry, i'm being ironic. Any mention of that particular gem of storytelling sets me in a weird semiamused semiirritated mood :)

Comment: I move that we grant Valorum emergency powers. Or at least swag.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida Gotcha. Sometimes irony goes right over my head :-) I too would have loved to see all the talk of trade negotiations followed in subsequent movies with the antics of trying to file a joint tax return without the secret getting out that you're married!

Comment: Do Jedi even pay taxes?

Comment: @Gremer Sounds like a good question to ask on this site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jedi Council typically communicated with the Supreme Chancellor or individual senators directly. It was common for members of the Jedi Council to meet with the Supreme Chancellor in person.

[image: Jedi meeting in Chancellor's office]

These meetings were especially frequent during the Clone Wars, to coordinate the strategy and movements of the Grand Army of the Republic and its Jedi generals.

It was also not unheard-of for individual senators to request and be granted an audience with members of the Jedi Council.

[image: Senator meeting with Jedi Council]