# Do Jedi pay taxes?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Inspires by the comments in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149356/how-much-official-communication-was-there-between-the-senate-and-the-jedi-counci?noredirect=1#comment383646_149356).

Is any money given to the Jedi Order taxed, or are they tax-free being that they're supposed to be the defenders of the Republic? Or do they not own money, and thus can't be taxed?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90561/if-jedi-arent-supposed-to-own-anything-then-where-do-they-get-their-money-from - Note that the commentator makes a distinction between taxpayers and Jedi

Comment: That reminds me of a genius paragraph about wizards and taxes from the *Reaper Man*.

Comment: @Gallifreian - Are you suggesting that tax collectors tend to come back missing their greedy fingers?

Comment: Related: [Star Wars: The Empire and Taxation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/104187/31394)

Comment: @Valorum:  `It was two hundred dollars per capita; if per capita was a problem, decapita could be arranged.` found [here](http://www.ealasaid.com/fan/vetinari/vl-reaper.html)

Comment: *The IRS is not as forgiving as I am*

Comment: The only two certainties in life are death and taxes. And since there is no death because there is the Force, I guess the Sith cover the other one. The Force shall free them, after all.

Comment: As a religious organization, they would be tax-exempt.

Comment: just opinion but since the Jedi are supposed to reject things like personal ownership, possessions, etc...it seems more likely that they would have a community 'petty cash' type pool for situations where they need funds for a mission

Comment: These are not the taxes you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The Jedi had money-they've used it at several points in the series(Ep 1, Qui-Gonn paying for ship parts with republic credits). But there is 0 mention of them paying any kind of taxes. In fact, there is more evidence pointing to Jedi receiving taxes in some small amount. 
We know that a lot of Jedi don't sleep at the Temple, which means they had to get their housing somehow. We know that no one ever comes to collect a monetary debt from a Jedi. We know Jedi are the Peacekeepers of the Galaxy, which hints at some kind of special police or military force. And we know they deal with high members of political standing, so it would be logical to deduce that Jedi don't pay taxes because they are received for the kind of work they do-risking their lives so others don't have to.
They could be paid because of what they do by rich donors, but we never see anyone paying for those services.